# Upgrade Sonar when plugins require to be upgraded

Tags: sonarqube

I'm trying to upgrade from Sonar 4.1.2 to 5.1.1 (but the problem would be the same if I wanted to upgrade to 4.2).
I use some plugins that needs to be upgraded. For example Android plugin should be upgraded from 0.1 to 1.1 (or 1.0 to upgrade to Sonar 4.2).

The sonar System updates page (my_sonar_server_url/updatecenter/system_updates) tells me to first upgrade the plugin, and shows me an "upgrade" button in front of that plugin. But clicking on it results in a message "Plugin android is needed to be installed at version greater or equal 1.1".[image]

I tried to go in the "Plugin Updates" tab, where the plugin upgrades are marked "Incompatible, requires to upgrade system".[image]

This seems inconsistent, and I wonder how I can make the upgrade.
Looking at [http://http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading) I presume I have to "manually upgrade the plugins". But how I can do that? Where can I download the required plugin version?

Answer (score 1):

For manual-upgrade I get the plugins here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.java

Download the file and put it in SONAR/plugins/extensions (not 100% sure of the correct path).

You can find the android plugin here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.android/sonar-android-plugin

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately, latest versions of some plugins are not in the repository yet (example: java plugin is in 3.2 in maven, but Sonar 5.1.1 requires 3.3). I searched more and find the plugin library there: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Library. I should have find it sooner ... Nethertheless, I installed a fresh new 5.1.1, then install the plugins, then change the SONARQUBE_HOME/conf/sonar.properties to point to the old database, open the Browse to http://localhost:9000/setup. And everything worked fine :-)